# django : Model filter on date ranges

Tags: django, django-models

How to get model filter on date ranges.
In my project using employee doj, i need to deign a table.
like employee who have joined less than three months , 3-6month, 6-12 months, 12-24 months.

```
Depart  < 3month  3-6months   6-12months  12-24months
----------------------------------------- ---- -----
  A dep   4        6             6           8

------------------------------------------------------
```

How to do this filter in django.

I have gone through this link ,but its confusing .

http://www.nerdydork.com/django-filter-model-on-date-range.html

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you explain which part of the linked article didn't work for you?

Answer (score 20):

The range filter works like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date__range=(range_start, range_end))
```

You can use that in conjunction with `datetime.timedelta` to get month periods. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()

# <3 months
three_months_ago = now - timedelta(months=3)
MyModel.objects.filter(date__range=(three_months_ago, now))
```